# Why doesn't the Gnome System Monitor show all memory usage?

Tags: process, gnome, virtualbox, memory, ram

In the Gnome System Monitor, it doesn't show my virtualbox process, which is running a VM using 4GB (out of 16GB) !! I even sorted the processes by memory size.
But in htop, everything seems correct.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anybody help ??

Comment: I would [ask this in their Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+addquestion). I could do that myself, but I don't use virtualbox. I use QEMU/KVM though, but it is show correctly in the System Monitor.